# How to define a CloudWatch Alarm on the sum of two metrics with CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I need to trigger an alarm when the sum of the same metric (`ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible`) on two different queues exceed the value of 100

In September '17, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375981/create-cloudwatch-alarm-on-multiple-sqs-queues) answer stated that the only way to do it was with a Lambda function getting the two values and summing them up via CloudWatch API.

At writing time, Feb. '19, it is possible to use "[Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html)", so there is no need to have a lambda function or an EC2 instance. Is it possible to use Metric Math to define an Alarm directly in CloudFormation ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is actually possible to implement the Alarm logic directly in CloudFormation.

Assuming to have two Scaling Policies `ECSScaleUp` and `ECSScaleDown`, the alarm definition will look like:

```
ECSWorkerSQSCumulativeAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    AlarmName: !Join ['-', [!Ref 'MyService', 'SQSCumulativeAlarm']]
    AlarmDescription: "Trigger ECS Service Scaling based on TWO SQS queues"
    Metrics:
      - Id: e1
        Expression: "fq + sq"
        Label: "Sum of the two Metrics"
      - Id: fq
        MetricStat:
          Metric:
            MetricName: ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible
            Namespace: AWS/SQS
            Dimensions:
              - Name: QueueName
                Value: !GetAtt [ FirstQueue, QueueName]
        Period: 60
        Stat: Average
        Unit: Count
        ReturnData: false
      - Id: sq
        MetricStat:
          Metric:
            MetricName: ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible
            Namespace: AWS/SQS
            Dimensions:
              - Name: QueueName
                Value: !GetAtt [ SecondQueue, QueueName]
          Period: 60
          Stat: Average
          Unit: Count
        ReturnData: false
    EvaluationPeriods: 2
    Threshold: 100
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
    AlarmActions:
      - !Ref ECSScaleUp
      - !Ref ECSScaleDown
    OKActions:
      - !Ref ECSScaleUp
      - !Ref ECSScaleDown
```

Comment: Under the "fq" MetricDataQuery the Period, Stat and Unit fields should be indented another two spaces so they're part of the MetricStat child rather than the MetricDataQuery.